# httrack: how to copy a website with email based username login

Tags: login, email, https

I'm trying to do an off-line copy a website that requires login with **HTTrack**. The question, although, it is quite more generic. Following this instructions http://www.httrack.com/html/faq.html#QM6 I understood that I must use the following structure to be logged-in:

```
https://username:password@www.website.com
```

The problem I'm facing is probably very simple for someone with html expertise.

How can I do to put a username that is actually an email address inside `https://username:password@` chain? Because as it is, when I put my username, the code is "cut" by the "@" of the email, instead of considering the whole stuff.

Thanks in advance!

(this is oriented to build a bash script, so the GUI solutions won't make it)

Comment: Have you tried the same command by only removing `www.`??

Comment: just tried, not working... I think it doesn't take "user@mail.com:password" as username and password... but only "user" and then search for the webaddress.

Comment: Try using `%40` or `&#64;` in place of `@` - *(like `%20` means the 'Space' character)*

Comment: ..using the string with double quotes doesn't work too?

Comment: sadly didn't worked. I was hoping that @wilf comment solve it, but no. @Hash, I already have a double quote because of httrack syntax:
`httrack "user@mail.com:password@http://www.website.com"`
I tried with single-double quotes, and double-double quotes without success.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should click on "Add URL" button according to screenshot given below.
[image]

I successfully copied the whole site by providing email and password using this way.
I hope this will help you too :)

Comment: thank you but it is a command line related question... this is a GUI based answer.

Comment: What about https websites ? I can't make it work using HTTrack ! Not working